# DateTime format changes after merging Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, pandas, merge

I have got two dataframe with a column named `time`, containing datetime representation of time, and a variable column. I want to merge these two dataframes, but for some reason this messes up the datetime format of `nn`.

I used this code to create the individual dataframes:

```
## ECG load
nn = pd.read_csv('D:\\path\\Nn.csv',delimiter=";",decimal=',',header=None,names=["time","ibi"])
fsEcg = 1024 # Sample frequency
tsEcg = mkdatMovis('2016-10-31T12:16:15.015') #datetime rep of Start time string
nn.loc[:,'time'] = nn.time/fsEcg # convert sample number to seconds
ecgTime = zip(tsEcg + datetime.timedelta(seconds=float(cmt)) for cmt in nn.time)
nn.loc[:,'time'] = ecgTime

## EDA load
eda = pd.read_csv('D:\\path\\eda.csv',\
                  delimiter=";",decimal=',',header=None,names=["eda"])
fsEda = 32
tsEda = mkdatMovis('2016-10-31T12:17:08.363')
cumEda = np.arange(len(eda),dtype=np.float64)/fsEda  # create time array in seconds
cumEda = pd.Series(cumEda)
edadat = pd.DataFrame()
edadat.loc[:,'time'] = zip(tsEda + datetime.timedelta(seconds=float(cmt)) for cmt in cumEda)
edadat.loc[:,'eda'] = eda
```

The dataframes are as follows:

```
>>> nn
                           time           nn
0    2016-10-31 12:16:26.409531   972.656250
1    2016-10-31 12:16:27.394883   985.351562
2    2016-10-31 12:16:28.379258   984.375000
3    2016-10-31 12:16:29.360703   981.445312
4    2016-10-31 12:16:30.407578  1046.875000
...
1448 2016-10-31 12:39:37.910508   845.703125

>>> edadat
                                time   eda
0      (2016-10-31 12:17:08.363000,)   2.0
1      (2016-10-31 12:17:08.363000,)   5.0
2      (2016-10-31 12:17:08.363000,)   5.0
3      (2016-10-31 12:17:08.363000,)   4.0
4      (2016-10-31 12:17:08.363000,)   4.0
....
41582  (2016-10-31 12:38:47.363000,)  36.0
```

After merging the dataframes with `df = edadat.merge(nn,on="time",how="outer")`, the data looks like this:

```
                                time  eda           nn
0      (2016-10-31 12:17:08.363000,)  2.0          NaN
1      (2016-10-31 12:17:08.363000,)  5.0          NaN
2      (2016-10-31 12:17:08.363000,)  5.0          NaN
3      (2016-10-31 12:17:08.363000,)  4.0          NaN
4      (2016-10-31 12:17:08.363000,)  4.0          NaN
...
43027            1477917574356797000  NaN   928.710938
43028            1477917575276719000  NaN   919.921875
43029            1477917576178086000  NaN   901.367188
43030            1477917577064805000  NaN   886.718750
43031            1477917577910508000  NaN   845.703125
```

**Why is the datetime form `nn` converted to unix after merging?** Don't I use exactly the same code for creating the time Series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is problem you have `tuples` in column `time`, so you need remove tuples by `str[0]` - select first element in each tuple in row of `DataFrame`:

```
edadat.time = edadat.time.str[0]
print (edadat)
                             time   eda
0      2016-10-31 12:17:08.363000   2.0
1      2016-10-31 12:17:08.363000   5.0
2      2016-10-31 12:17:08.363000   5.0
3      2016-10-31 12:17:08.363000   4.0
4      2016-10-31 12:17:08.363000   4.0
41582  2016-10-31 12:38:47.363000  36.0
```

Then use:

```
df = edadat.merge(nn,on="time",how="outer")
print (df)
                         time   eda           nn
0  2016-10-31 12:17:08.363000   2.0          NaN
1  2016-10-31 12:17:08.363000   5.0          NaN
2  2016-10-31 12:17:08.363000   5.0          NaN
3  2016-10-31 12:17:08.363000   4.0          NaN
4  2016-10-31 12:17:08.363000   4.0          NaN
5  2016-10-31 12:38:47.363000  36.0          NaN
6  2016-10-31 12:16:26.409531   NaN   972.656250
7  2016-10-31 12:16:27.394883   NaN   985.351562
8  2016-10-31 12:16:28.379258   NaN   984.375000
9  2016-10-31 12:16:29.360703   NaN   981.445312
10 2016-10-31 12:16:30.407578   NaN  1046.875000
11 2016-10-31 12:39:37.910508   NaN   845.703125
```

But I think better is use [`merge_ordered`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_ordered.html):

```
df1 = pd.merge_ordered(edadat, nn,on="time",how="outer")
print (df1)
                         time   eda           nn
0  2016-10-31 12:16:26.409531   NaN   972.656250
1  2016-10-31 12:16:27.394883   NaN   985.351562
2  2016-10-31 12:16:28.379258   NaN   984.375000
3  2016-10-31 12:16:29.360703   NaN   981.445312
4  2016-10-31 12:16:30.407578   NaN  1046.875000
5  2016-10-31 12:17:08.363000   2.0          NaN
6  2016-10-31 12:17:08.363000   5.0          NaN
7  2016-10-31 12:17:08.363000   5.0          NaN
8  2016-10-31 12:17:08.363000   4.0          NaN
9  2016-10-31 12:17:08.363000   4.0          NaN
10 2016-10-31 12:38:47.363000  36.0          NaN
11 2016-10-31 12:39:37.910508   NaN   845.703125
```

Comment: Thank you. That actually seems to work (though I will have to make some other changes now). But why were the time indices in `nn` no tuples then? And why did the tuples in `edadat` alter the `nn` time indices? Does that have something to do with type conversion? And final question, I thought `df.time = x` ought to be replaced by `df.loc[:,"time"] = time`. How is it correct now?

Comment: I think there is problem in `edadat` in `time` column is tuples because at least one row return tuples with two elements.

Comment: You can check it by `print (edadat[edadat.time.str.len() > 1])`